# How to handle "mutating method sent to immutable object" exception?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a class called Customer.

```
Customer *object; //in this object i have the following data varialbles.

object.customerName
object.customerAddress 
object.customerContactList
```

I declared customerContactList as NSMutableArray and also allocated and initialized.

Now I am adding or deleting from contactList.

```
//Adding.
[object.customerContactList addObject:editcontacts];// here editcontacts one of the object in contactList.

//Deleting.
[object.customerContactList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[theTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I am getting exception even it is NSMutableArray. Please help me.

Thank You,
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm jut guessing, because as Williham Totland said, we need to see your code.  How is the customerContactList property declared, implemented and assigned?

My guess is that somewhere you are using `copy` on the array.  If you send `copy` to an `NSMutalbeArray` you'll get an immutable copy back.  If your property is declared:

```
@property (copy) NSArray* customerContactList
```

you'll get an immutable array back when you use it.  You might even get an immutable array if you declare it thus (I'm not sure how clever the compiler is):

```
@property (copy) NSMutableArray* customerContactList
```

Comment: Thank you very much I am taking a copy of list into contact list using ' copy '. Now I am not getting that exception.

Answer (score 1):

You keep asking this question, and you keep getting the same answer: "Izit?". Before you can be helped any further on this point, you need to actually show some more code, like the interface declaration for `Customer`.

What you *should* do, at this juncture, is to add a method to `Customer` along the lines of `- (void)addToContactList:(id)contact`. Accessing collection objects directly on an object in the manner you are describing is hardly considered kosher.

And another thing: your properties *really* don't need to have the class name in their name; rather than `Customer *object; object.customerName;` you should have `Customer *customer; customer.name;` and so on. Makes for far more readable code.

And this bears repeating: You *cannot* get that exception if you have an `NSMutableArray`. That exception is unequivocal proof that what you have, in fact, is **not** an `NSMutableArray`; and **cannot be**. This is the function of the exception in question. This is what the exception is, does, and means. This is the essence of the exception, it's reason for being, or *raison d'etre*, if you will. In case it wasn't clear: The array you are attempting to add to is not mutable. It is ***immutable***.